# Выдает ошибку при запуске. Что неверно?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input()
if a<=3:
    print("You are a baby")
elif a>3 and a<18:
    print("You are a teenager")
else :
    if 18 >= a and a<60:
        print("You are an adult")
    else:
        if a>=60:
            print("You are an elder")
input()
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `input()` всегда возвращает строковое значение. Ошибка у вас возникает из-за того, что условный оператор `<=` не может сравнить строку и чиcло и поэтому выдает ошибку TypeError.

Если вы хотите иcпользовать `a` как число,то сделайте так:

```
a = int(input())
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
if a<=3:
    print("You are a baby")
elif a>3 and a<18:
    print("You are a teenager")
elif a>18 and a <60:
    print("You are an adult")
else:
    print("You are an elder")
```

Вроде должно сработать. Пайтон очень ответственно подходит к отсупам